# Email validation message Rails and foundation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

I am trying to display a message using foundation framework to validate and add email address.The validation happens as expected, but no messages get displayed. Is there something I am missing?

_messages.html.erb

```
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
    <div data-alert class="alert-box round <%= name.to_s == :notice ? "success" : "alert" %>">
      <%= content_tag :div, msg %>
      <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

contacts_controller.rb

```
    class ContactsController < ApplicationController
    def new
                @contact = Contact.new
    end

    def create
        @contact = Contact.new(secure_params) 
        if @contact.valid?
            @contact.update_spreadsheet
            flash[:notice] = 'You have been added'
            redirect_to root_path 

        else

            flash.now[:alert] = 'Not a valid email'
            redirect_to root_path
        end 
    end

    private

        def secure_params
            params.require(:contact).permit(:email)
        end

end
```

application.html.erb

```
 <header>
      <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
    </header>
      <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
      <%= yield %>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can try with `render partial: 'layouts/messages'`.
`partial` is the meaning of the underscore basically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within messages partial **_messages.html.erb**, you are comparing a string to a symbol which is the reason the message is not displayed.

name.to_s is an object of String class and

:notice is an object of Symbol class

Problem line:

```
<div data-alert class="alert-box round <%= name.to_s == :notice ? "success" : "alert" %>">
```

You should match `name.to_s == "notice"` here

Answer (score 0):

The issue was indeed with the _messages partial
changed

```
<div data-alert class="alert-box round <%= name.to_s == :notice ? "success" : "alert" %>">
```

to

```
<div data-alert class="alert-box round <%= name.to_s == 'notice' ? 'success' : 'alert' %>">
```

and all worked as expected.